# Periodic Message in Thread

Tags: android, handler

I have a activity (myActivity) and a thread (MyThread) , both with a handler which allow me to send message between the UI thread and myCustomThread.
Now i would like to call periodically (10sec)  the ALIVE message of the MyThread thread from MyActivity. How can i achieve that ?

**MyActivity :**

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    this.thread                 = new MyThread(activityHandler);
    this.threadHandler  = this.thread.gethandler();

    threadMessage           = this.threadHandler.obtainMessage();
    threadMessage.what  = AUTH;
    this.threadHandler.sendMessage(threadMessage);
}
```

**MyThread :**

@Override

```
public void run()
{

        Looper.prepare();

        this.threadHandler = initHandler();

        this.message        = this.activityHandler.obtainMessage();
        this.message.what   = CONNECTED;
        activityHandler.sendMessage(this.message);

        Looper.loop();

}

private Handler initHandler()
{
    return new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            switch(msg.what)
            {
                case AUTH : 
                {
                    auth();
                    break;
                }

                case ALIVE :
                {
                    sendAlive();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution with [sendEmptyMessageDelayed(ALIVE,10000)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29)

Long story short, i call once ALIVE from my UI thread and at the end of the sendAlive() method i'm sending a delayedMessage to the thread itself to re-call ALIVE after X milliseconds.

With this solution no need of a new Thread or timer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution really depends on what you are trying to put together...

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) is a walk through for performing an action on a timer as well as how to use a delayed post (the preferred way of executing on a schedule because it doesn't use a thread for the timer).  It is a good write up and they include the why.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Delayed post was a good solution. I'm using it without timer (see my previous answer) and it works great.  Thanks